# Simba ODBC Driver DSN Setup Cannot Test The Connection

Tags: windows-7, drivers, odbc

I'm having an issue with Simba ODBC Driver DSN Setup.

I'm using Service Authentication, can reach the catalog and dataset. So, the "Catalog (Project)" and "Dataset" dropdowns are filled with the correct names. However, the "Test" and "OK" buttons are disabled.

I have tried it on four different PCs. Two of them are Windows 7, one of them is Windows 10 and the last one is Windows Server 2012 R2. All of them 64-bit. The results are the same. Here are the screenshots:

- Simba ODBC Driver DSN Error

[image: Simba ODBC Driver DSN Error]

- Windows Server 2012 R2 Setup

[image: Win Server 2012 R2 Setup]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you share a screenshot of the setup windows?

Comment: Of course. I added a screenshot to the question.

Comment: Seems like one of your entered parameters is invalid. Hard to verify them from here.

Answer (score 0):

You have to populate Catalog (Project) via dropdown. Manual entry will not work.
For the Project to be listed in the dropdown, sufficent access level in the project is required for the service account.
"BigQuery Admin" on the project worked for me.

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that the OP filled in the “Catalog (Project)” field manually  rather than by using the dropdown? The question refers to the dropdowns.

Comment: If selected via dropdown the project show up as "<project name> <project id>" in that field. In the screenshot it is shown as "<project id>" only.

Comment: This is a GREAT answer ... but do we know why this should be?  What would possibly be wrong with entering a project ID manually?